# get column name in addition to the result (oracle)

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, select

I have a program in c# (asp.net environment) that dynamically runs ORACLE queries.
the queries can be like:

```
select * from app_costumers;
select a.first_name, a.last name, b.salary from app_costumers inner join app_costs b on a.id = b.id;
```

(As you can see, this is sometimes about a single table and sometimes more.
Sometimes writing the column names and sometimes using only in "*").

until now, I returned only the results,
But now I need to return the names of the results columns.

Do you have any idea how to do this?
(I can't use something like this:

```
SELECT column_name FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = UPPER ('app_costumers');
```

Because it only fits for one table ...).

Thank you

Comment: `USER_TAB_COLS` will only show tables/cols that your session user owns (is the schema name for). `ALL_TAB_COLS` will will all that your session users has privileges on, including its own tables. `DBA_TAB_COLS` will show cols for every table. But, depending on the C# library you use to run the query, you should be able to see the names/aliases of the query columns returned in the resultset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reader.GetName(i), for example:

```
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

var columns = new List<string>();

for(int i=0;i<reader.FieldCount;i++)
{
   columns.Add(reader.GetName(i));
}
```